# Simple Rust TcpStream client and server problem where client crash with "peer reset"

Tags: networking, rust, tcp

This server tries to send data to the client and the client tries to receive all the data. when a certain amount of data have been sent/received, the application exit.

the client code:

```rust
 use std::{env::args, io::Read, net::TcpStream, time::Instant};
fn main() {
    let addr = args()
        .nth(1)
        .unwrap_or_else(|| "localhost:2233".to_string());
    let size_m = args().nth(2).unwrap_or_else(|| "10".to_string());
    let size_m = size_m.parse::<usize>().unwrap();

    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect(addr.clone()).unwrap();
    println!(
        "Connected to {}, local address: {}",
        addr,
        stream.local_addr().unwrap()
    );
    let now = Instant::now();
    let mut buffer = vec![0; 1024 * 1024];
    for i in 0..size_m {
        stream.read_exact(buffer.as_mut_slice()).unwrap();
        println!("read {}MB", i + 1);
        println!(
            "average speed: {}MB/s",
            (i + 1) as f64 / now.elapsed().as_secs_f64()
        );
    }
    println!("total time: {} s", now.elapsed().as_secs_f64());
    println!(
        "speed: {} MB/s",
        size_m as f64 / now.elapsed().as_secs_f64()
    );
}
```

the server code:

```rust
use std::env::args;
use std::io::Write;
use std::net::TcpListener;

fn main() {
    let addr = args().nth(1).unwrap_or_else(|| ":::2233".to_string());
    let size_m = args().nth(2).unwrap_or_else(|| "10".to_string());
    let size_m = size_m.parse::<usize>().unwrap();
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(addr).unwrap();
    println!("Listening on {}", listener.local_addr().unwrap());
    if let Ok((mut stream, addr)) = listener.accept() {
        println!("Accepted connection from {}", addr);
        // create 1M buffer
        let buffer = vec![0; 1024 * 1024];
        for i in 0..size_m {
            stream.write_all(buffer.as_slice()).unwrap();
            println!("write {}MB", i + 1);
        }
        stream.flush().unwrap();
        //close stream
        // stream.shutdown(std::net::Shutdown::Both).unwrap();
    }
}
```

and I ran server like : `cargo run --bin speedtestserver :::2233 2`
client like: `cargo run --bin speedtestclient ::1:2233 2`

It can succeed in the same machine, but when to deploy to two different machines, the client says: "failed to fill whole buffer" or "peer reset".

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem, it's about the docker container. I ran the server in a docker container using `docker --rm ...`, when the program finished, the docker shut down the container, and the packets failed to get out I guess. When I ran the server on the host machine, the error disappeared.